# Declarative Pipeline Jenkins syntax error on mailbody

Tags: jenkins

I have created a declarative pipeline with a Jenkinsfile to email the build. I am getting a syntax error in Jenkins console output for this code.

```
stage("Email Build Status"){
            steps{
mailbody:'${env.JOB_NAME}-Build#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}-${currentBuild.currentResult}\n\nCheck Console output at ${env.BUILD_URL}to view the results',subject:'${env.JOB_NAME}-Build#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}-${currentBuild.currentResult}!!',to:'er.jayasree@yahoo.com'  
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got arguments to a function call

> ```
> mailbody:'…',to:'…'
> ```

but you're not actually calling any function.

`mail` is a function, `body` and `to` are arguments to that function

If you meant to use the `mail` function, you're missing a space in `mailbody` to separate `mail` (function) from `body` (argument):

```
mail body:'…', to:'…'
```

Comment: Stage Logs (Email Build Status)
 Mail -- ${env.JOB_NAME}-Build#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}-${currentBuild.currentResult}!! (self time 2s)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
emailext body: """
   ${env.JOB_NAME}-Build#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}-${currentBuild.currentResult}\n\nCheck Console output at ${env.BUILD_URL}to view the results
  """,
subject: "${env.JOB_NAME}-Build#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}-${currentBuild.currentResult}",
to: "er.jayasree@yahoo.com"
```

or Another Alternative way

```
emailext body: '${env.JOB_NAME}-Build#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}-${currentBuild.currentResult}\n\nCheck Console output at ${env.BUILD_URL}to view the results', subject: '${env.JOB_NAME}-Build#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}-${currentBuild.currentResult}', to: 'er.jayasree@yahoo.com'
```

Totally depends on you which above solutions suits better for you so use acorrding to it !!

Comment: but then got below error in jenkins console -Stage Logs (Email Build Status)
 Mail -- ${env.JOB_NAME}-Build#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}-${currentBuild.currentResult}!! (self time 2s)

Comment: @JayasreeSivaraj did pipeline get result as success or failure?